# Is it possible to get GCC to read from a pipe?

Tags: gcc, command-line, pipe, flex-lexer

I'm looking for an option to `gcc` that will make it read a source file from the standard input, mainly so I could do something like this to generate an object file from a tool like `flex` that generates C code (`flex`'s `-t` option writes the generated C to the standard output):

```
flex -t lexer.l | gcc -o lexer.o -magic-option-here
```

because I don't really care about the generated C file.

Does something like this exist, or do I have to use temporary files?

Comment: The generated C file is good to have around if you ever need to debug that code.

Comment: @laalto: That's a good point, but the code that flex generates is not very human readable anyways.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Yes, but you have to specify the language using the `-x` option:

```
# Specify input file as stdin, language as C
flex -t lexer.l | gcc -o lexer.o -xc -
```

Comment: I figured it might be - (many other tools use it), but I couldn't find anything about it in the man page...

Comment: Note that, here in 2019, this recently broke with gcc 8.2.1. It will now hang while reading from the pipe.

Comment: @ToddFreed: Assuming that the process generating the source file properly closed its output, then that sounds like it's a bug in GCC.  If you have a reproducible test case, I suggest you report that to the GCC maintainers.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to still give the file a name, for gcc diagnostics?

Comment: (It turns out one can use a preprocessor directive to give it a file name; this can be added on the first line of the input)

Comment: I noticed that using flex -t lexer.l | gcc -I<path> -o /dev/null -x c - doesn't consider include paths. is it beacuse of not using file

Answer (score 23):

```
flex -t lexer.l | gcc -x c -c -o lexer.o -
```

Basically you say that the filename is `-`. Specifying that a filename is `-` is a somewhat standard convention for saying 'standard input'. You also want the `-c` flag so you're not doing linking. And when GCC reads from standard input, you have to tell it what language this is with `-x` . `-x c` says it's C code.

Comment: I know what -c is, I just left it out for simplicity (because I have a lot of other options on flex and gcc too).