# hooking a source-file preprocessor before gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction

I want to preprocess files before gcc actually does its own preprocessing and parsing.
Actually this is my problem:

I have nonstandard extension added to a c++ .h file, which gcc wont understand, so i must preprocess this non-standard extensions into standard c++, and then push my output to gcc.

What then i need to do is to plug-in a preprocessor for file, which must be called when a condition on file is met (when this non-standard extensions are met).

How do i go about adding such a functionality? through code or command-line argument to gcc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to do this through g++. Just set up your makefile so that it knows about your precondition(s) and shells out to your preprocessor before even calling g++ at all.

Comment: since make can be told which program to call, it looks like the best option. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe text into GCC, see [Is it possible to get gcc to read from a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003644/is-it-possible-to-get-gcc-to-read-from-a-pipe).
This might be a solution for your needs, depending on whether you already have a tool that will do your preprocessing and generate output on stdout.

Or alternatively as Nicklas suggested, write a makefile rule to convert files with your non-standard extension into .cpp files.