# how to use stdin pipe as source input for gcc?

Tags: windows, gcc, pipe

This is my try:

CMD file:

```
@SET PATH=%PATH%;D:\mingw\bin
type test10.cpp | g++ -xc++ -o test10.exe
```

code (irrelevant here): `int main() {}`

error I get:

```
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I thought that the -x option is for signalizing stdin input, gcc itself said me that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get gcc to read from a pipe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003644/is-it-possible-to-get-gcc-to-read-from-a-pipe)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `-x` option specifies the input language, but it doesn't tell g++ to read from stdin. To do that, you can pass a single dash as a file name.

```
type test10.cpp | g++ -o test10.exe -x c++ -
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `here doc` in the interactive shell.
for example:

```
gcc -x c - <<eof
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
    int a = 10;
    static int sa = 10;

    a += 5;
    sa += 5;

    printf("a = %d, sa = %d\n", a, sa);
}


int main()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        foo();
}
eof
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702982/compiling-c-code-without-a-file/65425028#65425028)