# Compiling C++ code stored in a Ruby string without writing it into a file

Tags: c++, ruby

I'm writing a Ruby code which generates a string containing a C++ program. For instance the Ruby string may contain:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;int main(){cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;return 0;}
```

In order to run the C++ program stored in the Ruby string, I write the string into a file named c_prog.cpp, then use:

```
%x( g++ c_prog.cpp -o output )
```

to compile the C++ program in the file, then use:

```
value = %x( ./output )
```

and then print the value.

Since the C++ program stored in the Ruby string is very long (thousands of LOC), writing it to the file wastes some time. Is there any way I can compile the program stored in the string without writing it into a file? I mean something like:

```
%x( g++ 'the ruby string' -o output )
```

instead of:

```
%x( g++ c_prog.cpp -o output )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in a single dash as a file name to tell `g++` to read from STDIN. So,

```
%x( echo 'the ruby string' | g++ -o output -x c++ - )
```

should do the trick. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563343/how-to-use-stdin-pipe-as-source-input-for-gcc).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `PTY` library to pipe directly in to the `g++` process:

```
require 'pty'

m, s = PTY.open
r, w = IO.pipe
pid = spawn("g++ -o output -x c++ -", :in=>r, :out=>s)
r.close
s.close
w.puts "#include <iostream>\n int main(){std::cout << \"Hello World\" << std::endl;}"
w.close
```