# Pipe file contents in g++ to compile

Tags: g++, pipe

Is it possible to pipe the contents of a file into `g++` to compile a program?

I want to do this because I want to use  a file from a database rather than a physical file on a disk. The file contents can be easily retrieved via an API I have made.

For instance, I would like to do something like:

```
g++ contents_of_file -o executable
```

Thanks a lot.

Sam.

Comment: same for gcc, same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003644/is-it-possible-to-get-gcc-to-read-from-a-pipe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can pipe to gcc if you specify the language using the `-x` option;

```
echo "int main(){}" | gcc -Wall -o testbinary -xc++ -
```

Comment: seems like choice of gcc/g++ is important; i get link errors when trying to use `gcc -xc++` on c++ code, but linking succeeds with `g++ -xc++`

Answer (score 0):

more fun:

```
alias true="gcc -xc++<(echo 'main()<%int(*)(int*)=6 "\?"<[:0:>;%>')&&a.out"
```

hey, works for me.