# How to compile code from stdin?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

The code is quite simple :

```
test$ cat test.cpp

int main()
{
}
```

Is there a way to compile the code that is coming from a standard output?

I have tried this :

```
cat test.cpp | g++ -
```

and some variations, but none produced executable.

---

Just some clarifications. I have a program which preprocess a file, and produces another file which I want to compile. I thought about not creating this intermediate file, but to instead produce the object file directly.

Comment: That’s stdin, not stdout.

Comment: Why are people so interested in compiling from standard input? Is it that hard to generate a file and compile that?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas My motto is : skip a middle man :)

Comment: Well, you are `cat`-ing a file... so the middle man is there. If your intention was typing directly into the compiler, then chances are that for anything not absolutely trivial you will make a typo and will have to retype (I know, I have used `cat` as an editor a few times which is fine if you never mistype)...

Comment: Don't do that. If you generate C or C++ code, generate it in some temporary file (perhaps in a *tmpfs* filesystem like `/tmp/`), and fork a `gcc` or a `make` process to compile it. Read [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17709877/841108)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas No, ´cat´ is not there. I have something else. A program which parses a header, and creates some code, which needs to be compiled into an obj file.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Any specific reason not to do it? I do not really care for the speed of the compilation.

Comment: Read [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17709877/841108) which gives a lot of reasons for not doing it.

Comment: For my part, I just needed to check the presence of a header. So, not creating a file is simpler than creating it then remove it. My solution: ``` is_header_present() { header_name=$1 gcc -o /dev/null $CFLAGS -x c++ - <<EOTEST #include "$header_name" int main() { return 0; } EOTEST return $? } ```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The compiler would have probably told you:

```
-E or -x required when input is from standard input
```

Try

```
cat test.cpp | g++ -x c++ -
```

Comment: Yes, it told me, but it didn't tell to put c++ after. After adding c++ it works

Comment: @BЈовић In these cases, you are supposed to read the documentation of the particular compiler flag you will be using. `-x` is documented to require the language as its argument.

Comment: @H2CO3 The error message is not helpful at all (if you do not provide the language). Also, the ´-´ has to be at the end. Try to find such details in g++ documentation

Comment: @devnull Please explain the need for that last `-`; it appears it can be omitted, yet is somehow necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this ?

```
$ cat tst.cpp | g++ -x c++ -
```

I have just tried it under Cygwin and had no problem.