# List of object files to gcc format

Tags: bash, gcc

I'm trying to link all my files with object *.o extension in my directory.
I tried to use:

```
for i in $(find . -name "*.o" -type f); 
    do
        echo $i >> myFiles  
    done
```

Then I need:

```
gcc -o myFile <myFiles
```

> gcc: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated.

Comment: Try to throw it all away and use one command: `gcc -o myfile $(find . -type f -name *.o)`

Answer (score 1):

I see several problem in your approach:

`find` [should not be used in a loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice), but rather with a `-fprint <file>`. So in your case:

```
find . -name "*.o" -type f -fprintf myfiles
```

Secondly, redirecting your file to `gcc` stdin will not work as you think, as it uses the input as the *source* of the code: [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702982/compiling-c-code-without-a-file). What you want instead is to expand the list of objects to a list of arguments:

```
cat myfiles | xargs gcc -o myFile
```

`xargs` does it nicely. But as @n.m. mentioned, you could do everything at once with a command substitution:

```
gcc -o myfile $(find . -type f -name *.o -print0)
```

The only difference I suggest is to use a `-print0` so that find put a `\0` at the end of a find instead of a `\n`.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Try this one
Then you will be able to complile the code.

```
gcc -o (filename filename.c)
```

> example
> gcc -o nikesh nikesh.c