# How to run code contained in clipboard

Tags: python, macos, clipboard

How can i directly run the contents of the clipboard, I tried using the command `python pbpaste` but it said **python: can't open file 'pbpaste': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**  does the code have to be contained in a file to run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `pbpaste` produces its output on the standard output and Python can take its input from the standard input, you can simply pipe them:

```
pbpaste | python
```

Comment: That is what i am looking for. Thanks, but why won't it work for **gcc** i tried this command `pbpaste | gcc` but it gave me this error **i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files** my clipboard contains a simple hello world program.

Comment: `gcc` is a different beast, AFAIK it doesn't accept its input from stdin. You could create a temporary file instead (you can e.g. use `mktemp` for that purpose).

Comment: @kylek, Apparently [gcc can accept input from stdin if you specify the language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003644/is-it-possible-to-get-gcc-to-read-from-a-pipe).