# Passing go code directly into go run without a file

Tags: go

Is it possible to pass a string of go code into `go run` instead of `go run /some/path/script.go`? I tried:

```
echo "some awesome go code here" | go run
```

But does not work. Thanks.

Comment: One-liner alternative: `echo "something" > x.go && go run x.go`

Comment: Don't have a computer handy to try it, but I suspect this would work? `echo "code code code" | go run /dev/stdin`

Comment: go run /dev/stdin doesn't work. Go checks that the file name is `*.go` . So I tried `ln -s /dev/stdin stdin.go`. But this happened:
 http://pastebin.com/YF1rv1bG

My Hypothesis is that go tries to seek. Which breaks if the input file is stdin.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there is such an option. At least not with the standard `*g` compilers or 
`go run`.

You can try using [gccgo](http://golang.org/doc/install/gccgo) as [GCC supports reading from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003644/is-it-possible-to-get-gcc-to-read-from-a-pipe).

Answer (score 3):

Since I thought that this would be a useful thing to have, I wrote a relatively small Python script that achieves what I think you want. I called it `go-script`, and here are some usage examples:

```
# Assuming that test.go is a valid go file including package and imports
$ go-script --no-package < test.go

# Runs code from stdin, importing 'fmt' and wrapping it in a func main(){}
$ echo 'fmt.Println("test")' | go-script --import fmt --main
$ echo 'fmt.Println("test")' | go-script -ifmt -m
```

Help:

```
Usage: go-script [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i PACKAGE, --import=PACKAGE
                        Import package of given name
  -p, --no-package      Don't specify 'package main' (enabled by default)
  -m, --main            Wrap input in a func main() {} block
  -d, --debug           Print the generated Go code instead of running it.
```

The source (also available [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/x3ro/7168195)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
from optparse import OptionParser
import os
import sys

parser = OptionParser()

parser.add_option("-i", "--import", dest="imports", action="append", default=[],
                  help="Import package of given name", metavar="PACKAGE")

parser.add_option("-p", "--no-package", dest="package", action="store_false", default=True,
                  help="Don't specify 'package main' (enabled by default)")

parser.add_option("-m", "--main", dest="main", action="store_true", default=False,
                  help="Wrap input in a func main() {} block")

parser.add_option("-d", "--debug", dest="debug", action="store_true", default=False,
                  help="Print the generated Go code instead of running it.")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

stdin = ""
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    stdin += "%s\n" % line

out = ""
if options.package:
    out += "package main\n\n"

for package in options.imports:
    out += "import \"%s\"\n" % package

out += "\n"
if options.main:
    out += "func main() {\n%s\n}\n" % stdin
else:
    out += stdin

if options.debug:
    print(out)
else:
    tmpfile = "%s%s" % (os.environ["TMPDIR"], "script.go")
    f = open(tmpfile, 'w')
    print(out, file=f)
    f.close()
    os.execlp("go", "", "run", tmpfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
cat <<EOF | tee /tmp/blah.go | go run /tmp/blah.go

package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello, World!")
}
EOF
```

If you want to not have to open a file and edit it first. Although I wouldn't find this super practical for every day use.

Comment: Thanks, but still this is writing the source code to disk `/tmp/blah.go`. Anyway without writing a file?