# Compiling a Fortran Program with input from the pipe

Tags: fortran, pipe, stdin

I am trying to compile a Fortran program by submitting the input via pipe. Can GNU Fortran compiler read the source input from the pipe

Comment: I doubt it as the defaults for compilation depend upon the file extension, which won't be present in a pipe, but I can't claim that I know for sure.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003644/is-it-possible-to-get-gcc-to-read-from-a-pipe .Unfortunately, the -x only handles C, C++ and assembler: not Fortran