# On windows 10, how to get gcc to compile from standard input

Tags: windows, gcc, command, line

I've seen this post that tells how to get gcc to compile from standard input (type file.c | gcc -x c -):

[Is it possible to get GCC to read from a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003644/is-it-possible-to-get-gcc-to-read-from-a-pipe)

But it does not work on windows 10. I always get "The system cannot find the file specified" in spite of having tried it every way I can imagine.

Anyone know the trick?

And I can't change the version of gcc we're using (I've heard standard input compile with gcc in mingw works on windows).

Comment: This command works for me (`type file.c | gcc -x c -`). Which file isn't found, `file.c` or `gcc`?

Comment: Wow. I went to go get the answer to your question and viola! It worked! Looks like I had copied/pasted / in the path instead of \. THANK YOU FOR ASKING!

Answer (score 0):

My own example works just fine. It was my mistake!